# rails_admin:install failing ( bad file descriptor error )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-admin

I want to install the **rails_admin gem**, but when I run the command `rails g rails_admin:install` I get a bad file descriptor error. See below. how to handle it?

```
$ rails g rails_admin:install
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline/ansi.rb:120:in `raw': Bad file descriptor (Errno::EBADF)
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline/ansi.rb:120:in `cursor_pos'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:349:in `may_req_ambiguous_char_width'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:208:in `inner_readline'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/reline.rb:188:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:235:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/line_editor/readline.rb:20:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/line_editor.rb:7:in `readline'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb:442:in `ask_simply'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/shell/basic.rb:85:in `ask'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/shell.rb:60:in `ask'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails_admin-2.2.1/lib/generators/rails_admin/utils.rb:13:in `ask_for'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rails_admin-2.2.1/lib/generators/rails_admin/install_generator.rb:13:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `block in invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:134:in `invoke_all'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/generators.rb:275:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands/generate/generate_command.rb:26:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.4.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
        from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

**System Specs:**

- Windows 10 X64
- Ruby 2.7.4
- Rails 6.1.4